# How do I store the second line of output into a variable in Batch?

Tags: batch-file

I want to run this command:

```
wmic useraccount where name='%username%' get sid
```

It outputs 3 lines:

```
SID
12345
*blank space*
```

I need to store the `sid` number, the second line, as a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for /f "skip=1delims=" %%a in (
 'wmic useraccount where name="%username%" get sid'
) do set "sid=%%a"&goto next
:next
```

or

```
set "sid="
for /f "skip=1delims=" %%a in (
 'wmic useraccount where name="%username%" get sid'
) do if not defined sid set "sid=%%a"
```

The `skip=1` skips the first line of the output from th `wmic` command (note that using this format, the inner quotation needs `"`). From there, in the first example the `for` loop is abruptly terminated and in the second, the variable `sid` is assigned on the first line following the skipped line and thereafter following lines are ignored.

Comment: Thank you! That blank space was really messing me up, but the second solution you gave worked great.